# React styled-components fade in/fade out

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to build a React component to handle fading in and fading out. In  the following code, if I pass `out` as a prop to the component, it is disaplayed as hidden before animating out. I'm trying to have it fade in by default, then fade out when I pass in the `out` prop. Anyone see a solution to this problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const fadeIn = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: scale(.25);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;

const fadeOut = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(.25);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;

const Fade = styled.div`
  ${props => props.out ?
    `display: none;`
   : `display: inline-block;`
   }
  animation: ${props => props.out ? fadeOut : fadeIn} 1s linear infinite;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Fade>&lt;test&gt;</Fade>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[WebpackBin running example](http://www.webpackbin.com/Eydur2FDG)

Comment: If I were you, I would check out the ReactCSSTransitionGroup add-on. It's easy to use, and the example that they give does what you are trying to do https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup

Comment: @denvaar AFAIK, ReactCSSTransitionGroup is going to be deprecated soon, so I am trying to avoid using that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're setting the display property to none when props.out is true. That's why you're not seeing any animation, because before that can even start you've already hidden the component!

The way to do a fade out animation is to use the visibility property instead and transition that for the same amount of time as the animation takes. (see [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property))

Something like this should solve your issues:

```
const Fade = styled.default.div`
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: ${props => props.out ? 'hidden' : 'visible'};
  animation: ${props => props.out ? fadeOut : fadeIn} 1s linear;
  transition: visibility 1s linear;
`;
```

```js
const fadeIn = styled.keyframes`
  from {
    transform: scale(.25);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;

const fadeOut = styled.keyframes`
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(.25);
    opacity: 0;
  }
`;

const Fade = styled.default.div`
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: ${props => props.out ? 'hidden' : 'visible'};
  animation: ${props => props.out ? fadeOut : fadeIn} 1s linear;
  transition: visibility 1s linear;
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      visible: true,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        visible: false,
      })
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Fade out={!this.state.visible}>&lt;test&gt;</Fade>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

*Note: Your fadeOut animation also went from 0 to 1 opacity, instead of the other way around. I've fixed that in the snippet too.*